# javafx get data from execute query

Tags: loops, javafx, get

Can someone tell me why this is failing at

> **row.add(rs.getString(i))**

```
rs=pst.executeQuery();
while(rs.next())
{
    ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Date, Number>> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    for(int i =1; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        row.add(rs.getString(i)); 
    }
}
```

The error i get is

> no suitable method found for add(String)
>       method Collection.add(Series) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Series)
>       method List.add(Series) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Series)

I'm not sure what I should change.

Comment: You have created an `ObservableList` of type `XYChart.Series<Date, Number>` and trying to add a `String` to it.

Comment: Hi i thought as much, but what should my rs.get*****(i) be?